# CiviEvent registration, edit wording relating to a drop down menu

Tags: civievent

How can I edit the wording in a set field beside a drop down box when a person is registering to attend an event? They could also use the drop down box to register a co-worker.
I.e., current wording says "Register someone at your organization" and we want to tweak to say "Register yourself or someone at your organization." 
Is this possible? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Word Replacement feature under Administer > Customise to make these sorts of changes ie at /civicrm/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1